# Error in PWA Flutter project related to ScaffoldMessengerState

Tags: flutter, dart, progressive-web-apps, flutter-web

I am getting error in Flutter PWA application for the below code

CODE

```
static final GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState> scaffoldMessengerKey =
      GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();
```

ERROR

```
error: The name 'ScaffoldMessengerState' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.
```

Not able to understand why such error is there.

Please guide further thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your flutter version. These changes landed in 1.23.0-13.0.pre. Its not available in stable release yet. Check [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/scaffold-messenger#timeline)

This should be ideally available in the beta channel as per the release list [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases)